# How can I implement an uninstall method for an OSGi bundle under Apache Felix?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have a number of OSGi bundles installed in an application which uses the Apache Felix OSGi implementation. Some of these bundles need to run extra steps when they are uninstalled. For example deleting temp files or removing related rows in a database or additional logging. The business rules expect this to happen when the plugin is uninstalled not when it is stopped.

I am aware of the start and stop methods on the BundleActivator but I am not able to figure out where I can implement an uninstall method.

I have also tried implementing a BundleListener. This appears to be called on start but not for uninstall. I am registering my BundleListener in the start method of my BundleActivator. Should I register it somewhere else?

What is the correct way to implement code which runs when an an OSGi bundle is uninstalled using Apache Felix?

Comment: This resource comes up with every possible search term I can think of: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/23/how-to-track-lifecycle-changes-of-osgi-bundles/ it seems to catch the uninstall events but my code does not. There are also several Apache Felix examples for a ServiceListener but none for a BundleListener.

Comment: yes, that blog mentions BundleWatcher interface which can help, but you problem is specific to Felix implementation .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bundle cannot observe it own UNINSTALLED event because its BundleListeners are removed during bundle stop. You would need another bundle, which is not stopped, to observe the UNINSTALLED event and perform any desired processing.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is the implementation I used. I have a BundleListener registered against a "root activator" BundleContext which is then able to listen to events for all of my OSGI plugins. The Listener is responsible for deciding if it is a plugin type it needs to act on. This works, but its a little awkward. I like @Puce's approach below, time permitting I will re-implement using a BundleTracker.

Comment: A BundleTracker is a better BundleListener. But the basic answer is the same: A bundle cannot process its own UNINSTALLED event. You need to have another (active) bundle do any desired processing.

Answer (score 2):

As the others said, I don't think you can do this in the bundle itself. You probably will have to use another bundle for this.

In that other bundle you could e.g. register a declarative service (e.g. using the *Apache Felix SCR* annotations) and use a `BundleTracker`/ `BundleTrackerCustomizer` to listen for bundles getting added and removed.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation for BundleTracker and it seems like that only gets called when a bundled enters or leaves the active state. Does it handle entering the uninstalled state?

Comment: AFAIK, the constructor takes a stateMask and the possible states are: UNINSTALLED,INSTALLED, RESOLVED,STARTING, STOPPING,ACTIVE

Comment: Yes it does. Cool.  http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/BundleTracker.html#BundleTracker(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext, int, org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTrackerCustomizer)

Comment: As stated above, I like this solution better even though I found an implementation which works using a `BundleListener` instead of a `BundleTracker`